# Alternative to QuerySet when you have a Single Instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a query set which filters a resource based on whether a user has access to it or not:

```
   resources = Resource.objects.user_access(user).all()
```

Let's say I have a single resource instance already. Should I then implement a property in my Resource model with the same logic as in my user_acesss Query Set. where I again check if they has access? Like this:

```
  resource.has_user_access(user)
```

I suppose I'm conscious of the fact that I'm repeating the logic that checks if the user has access in two places. If I were to put that logic into its own method, I guess it would be a static method in the Resource class.